# How to setup a single-key shortcut to cycle the second language inputs?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In my day-by-day work, I type texts in various languages. My usual behavior is that at each given moment I toggle between only two, e.g.:

- English and Ukrainian
- English and Thai
- English and German

…but never e.g. Thai and German.

It is fairly easy to setup everything *except the cyclic change the second input* (Ukrainian, Thai, German). Currently, I simply assign them with individual shortcuts, e.g.:

- Ukrainian <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>;
- Thai <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>;
- German <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

So, if I'm, for example, in English+Ukrainian pair, I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, and further pressing the layout switch (I'm using <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>) switches between English+German only.

This is a (poorly drawn) diagram of what I need:

[image: Cyclic diagram]

Question: **is possible to replace the whole bunch of Alt+Digits with a single cycling key?**
In terms of the diagram above, I want to replace many different Key2's with a single one.

---

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with KDE desktop.

My `~/.config/kxkbrc` contains the following (split the line to fit):

```
LayoutList=us,ua,th,de
LayoutLoopCount=2
Options=grp_led:scroll,grp:rwin_switch,compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,
        nbsp:level2,grp:rctrl_toggle,misc:typo
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but is this what you are looking for? https://askubuntu.com/questions/879122/input-language-groups-switching-windows-style/879178#879178

Comment: Or this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/871678/how-can-i-quickly-switch-between-two-out-of-multiple-languages/871686#871686

Comment: @JacobVlijm, thanks a lot, this may work if I set the groups like `(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)` and find some another tool instead of `gsettings` to work with KDE. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to cycle between all your input source.

---

You can change the shortcut in the same settings window where you can add new input sources. You can find it under `System Setting` > `Keyboard` > `Text Entry` (small button/link in the bottom left corner of `Keyboard` window).

Here you can see the `Text Entry` settings window:

[image: Text Entry window]

Comment: Thanks, but cyclic change **is** the system default. This is what `grp:(whatever)_toggle` actually does. This is not what I need simply because removing `LayoutLoopCount=2` would ruin the single-key switching between the two selected inputs.